# REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES issue when publish to Goole Play Console

Tags: android, flutter, permissions, google-play-console

I have an app to submit to do internal testing in Google Play. But having an issue related to `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` in previous build. I already remove the this in new build (9).

Now in my Google Play Account have this list of old build
[image]

when i try to submit my new build (9) without the `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`, it still prompt the same error relate to `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES`,

this are the build that affected. how can i handle this
[image]